# sly.js load page/initiate without animation

Tags: jquery, sly-scroller

I have posted this question in the Google group for sly.js, but I want to increase my possibility of getting an answer so I'm posting here as well.

I am using sly.js to create a horizontal nav menu.  When the page in which the nav menu resides loads, it runs an animation to scroll the active item into the center of the window. When another nav item is made active, the page reloads with new data, and the animation to scroll the active item to the center happens again.

I am curious if it is possible, with sly, to load a page with an active element, with the active element already centered, and without running the animation.

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have? This will make increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: I don't have one specific piece of code that I need assistance with, I'm just curious if what I want to do is possible.